# Does the size modifier affect touch and ranged touch attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, attack-roll

Since the rules are poorly described for touch and ranged touch attacks, should the size modifier apply when making these types of attacks?

The [attack roll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Roll) section is really meant for weapons and not magic, but it does list the size modifier from the [space and reach](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A creature's size modifier on attack rolls usually applies to *all* of the creature's attacks

Unless exceptions apply, a creature's size modifier on attack rolls applies on all attack rolls that the creature makes, whether the attack is a melee attack, a melee touch attack, a ranged attack, or a ranged touch attack. While [Attack Bonus](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#attack-bonus) *does* specify melee weapons (and [Touch Spells in Combat](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#touch-spells-in-combat) on Touch Attacks says, "Touching an opponent with a touch spell is considered to be an armed attack") and ranged weapons, I've never seen a creature's size modifier *excluded* from its attack roll when the creature uses, for instance, a natural weapon or a ranged touch attack.

(For example, a [dark naga](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/naga.html#naga-dark) possesses a base attack bonus of +7 and a Strength modifier of +2 yet with its bite its attack bonus is, without explanation, +8, but that mysterious additional −1 can be explained by the creature's Large size. Likewise, the [azruverda](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary3/azruverda.html#azruverda) possesses a base attack bonus of +12, a Dexterity modifier of +2, and the feat [Weapon Focus](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#weapon-focus) (acid), yet with its acid—a ranged touch attack—its attack bonus is +13, the mysterious additional −2 explained neatly by the creature's Huge size.)

Elsewhere—such as on the [Table: Size Bonuses and Penalties](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterAdvancement.html#table-2-2-size-changes), in the *Advanced Race Guide* on [Size Quality](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/raceBuilder/racialQualities.html#size-quality), and in the description of the transmutation subschool [polymorph](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#polymorph) ("If a polymorph spell causes you to change size, apply the size modifiers appropriately, changing your… attack bonus…")—a creature's size modifier seems to be considered a modifier on attack rolls *generally* rather than a *specific* modifier that applies only on attacks made with melee and ranged weapons.

As a creature's size modifier is applied to all its attacks in other parts of the game, I suspect [Attack Bonus](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#attack-bonus) is written with the typical PC in mind—the typical PC usually making attacks with melee weapons and ranged weapons—, rather than Attack Bonus making a broader statement about how size bonuses function throughout the game.